# How do limiting access through a iron-router in meteor app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

i have routing file which lock like:

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('gameSmall', {path: '/'});
    this.route('gameMedium', {path: '/game-medium'});
    this.route('gameLarge', {path: '/game-large'});
});
```

etc.

if i want to limiting access to some of path (only for some user who has password), can i configure it in router file? or only through native js in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron Router does not support limiting access by a configuration file. Instead you define access in your js source.
You can limit access to routes globally and per route. Both use the `onBeforeAction` event to evaluate access to the route(s).
`onBeforeAction` accepts a callback function where you write your access rule.

A global `onBeforeAction` event might look something like this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (!Meteor.isServer) {
      // Check the user. Whether logged in, but you could check user's roles as well.
      if (!Meteor.userId()) {
          this.render('pageNotFound'); // Current route cancelled -> render another page
      } else {
          this.next(); // Continue with the route -> will render the requested page
      }
  } 
}, 
{
    except: ['gameSmall']
});
```

Notice the `except` field in the second parameter. It contains an array of routes to be excluded from the onBeforeAction and therefore these are always rendered. There is also a field `only` which does the opposite, include routes to be evaluated by the onBeforeAction.

Also note that I used a template pageNotFound (404 page). You can define that page in IR's configuration like this:

```
Router.configure({
    notFoundTemplate: 'pageNotFound'
});
```

Comment: why we use (!Meteor.isServer) ? i think route always work on client side?

Comment: @Sarkis Arutiunian, IR does support server side routes as well, that's why I put Meteor.isServer in there. Your code does not need it because you use client side routes only.